# Insertar en bd con cakephp

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp, model-view-controller

cada vez que recargo la pagina me vuelve a insertar los datos es mas al actualizar la pagina los input me quedaban con la información que se había ingresado por lo cual me toco limpiar los input con js al cargar la pagina.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".txtClient").val("");
    $(".txtNeed").val("");
    $(".txtObjective").val("");

});
```

Home.ctp

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h1 id="h1IndexTitulo" class="lang" key="h1IndexTitulo">Laboratorio estrategico</h1>
    <h4 class="lang" key="h4FirstTexto">
        Diseñamos a través de las necesidades de <br> marca la mejor ruta 
        para cumplir con sus <br> objetivos y alcanzar resultados.

    </h4>

    <div class="col-md-6">




        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Need', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
        ?>

        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Para que marca vamos a trabahar?",
                'key' => 'lblClient', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
            'class' => 'validador txtClient lang', 'key' => 'txtClient'));
        echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
                'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
            . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
            'rows' => '4', 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
        echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
                'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
            . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
            . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4',
            'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang', 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
        ?>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
            <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-co" value="es"></span> Español'>Español</option>
            <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="en"></span> English'>English</option>
        </select>


        <?php
        $options = array(
            'class' => 'lang',
            'label' => 'Enviar y continuar',
            'key' => 'btnFormNeed'
        );
        echo $this->Form->end($options);
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
 public function home() {

    return null;//Esto es para que no inserte cada vez que hago un cambio en la pagina
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->loadModel('Need');
        $this->Need->create();
        if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Need->save(array(
                    'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es una imagen de lo que muestra el sql al recargar la pagina
[image: Sql]

Como pueden ver al recargar hace un insert de los datos que se habian ingresado anteriormente, y no se como enviar eso.

Datos repetidos de la BD:

[image: BD]

Cada registro ha sido por cada vez que actualizo la pagina por cambios en la vista o en alguna otra cosa ya sea Js o Css.

Comment: No está muy claro cual es el problema

Comment: Ya subo a una imagen adicional

Comment: El problema es que no validas si estás recibiendo un formulario y tampoco lo limpiabas al guardarlo. No es claro qué quieres que pase al guardar.

Comment: Es que no esta terminada, por ahora solo estaba probando la inserción en una base de datos. Pero hago la pregunta porque me ha pasado en varios formularios.

Comment: Al final eso va a ser un wizard pero se supone que al insertar va a otra pagina o quizas lo haga por ajax pero por ahora debo corregir los errores de ese insert, y la vdd no se lo veo, ps segui un ejemplo de otra pagina.

Comment: Como valido si estoy recibiendo un formulario? no es con el is("post") que verifico que venga sea llamado?

Comment: Intenta agregar `$this->request->data = array()` despues de tu`$this->Need->save(...)` para vacíar la variable

Comment: Voy a hacerlo y te cuento

Comment: Ya lo intente y no funciono